# CD-ROM drive periodically clicking even though empty

Tags: laptop, compact-disc, optical-drive

I have a DELL Latitude E6540 with a CD-ROM drive and Windows 7. Every 30 minutes or so the CD-ROM makings a clicking or rubbing noise even though it is empty. What is going on?

It's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the laser moving backwards and forwards. For some reason it's trying to read a CD that isn't there ... Could be a program you have running that intermittently tries to read the CD.

Although you want to make sure it's not your HDD ... Could be getting the click of death, in which case you want to back up all your data before you lose it

Comment: The laptop only has an SSD, no HDD. If its the laser, then the question becomes, who or what, is trying to read the disk that is not there, and how can I make it stop?